# Set timeout to an http request in Tornado

Tags: python, timeout, httprequest, tornado

I have this part of code:

```
como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port, 
                        '/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s'])

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)
```

where I do an http request. I would add a connection timeout, to be sure that the previous code is been executed, so I can find my response.

How can I add the timeout? I have to add it into the tornado.gen.Task call? I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `HTTPRequest` class to add a timeout to the request, instead of just passing the url to `fetch`.  Try:

```
request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=como_url, connect_timeout=20.0, request_timeout=20.0)
response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, request)
```

See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest

Comment: It doesn't work. I set the timeouts to 2.0 to fast the response, but doesn't work.

Comment: Connect timeout means that the request will be done after <time> seconds? Why doesn't work so??

Comment: With this code, if I print response, I have: 
`HTTPResponse(code=200,request_time=0.30609703063964844,buffer=<io.BytesIO object at 0x276a1d0>,_body=None,time_info={},request=<tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest object at 0x2764310>,effective_url='http://131.114.52.207:44444/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s',headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},error=None)`
As you can see, request_time=0.......

Comment: If I write 
`request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=como_url, connect_timeout=5.0, request_timeout=5.0)

        print request.connect_timeout`
I obtain 5.0 so it works... but doesn't work!

Comment: you probably get this, but just to get clear: `HTTPRequest.request_timeout` is only limiting value whereas `HTTPResponse.request_time` is the actual time of finished request.

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered this problem, sometimes timeout doesn't work.
Reason is `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient.max_clients` reach max value.

In `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient.fetch_impl`, if number of `self.active` greater than number of `max_clients` then `timeout_handle` be assigned none.

So you add increase tornado instance or `max_clients`, can solve it