# How to set the request timeout in a Tornado server?

Tags: python, tornado, kaldi

I'm running the [gstreamer server](https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server) for kaldi, which uses tornado internally to provide an HTTP end-point for transcription, e.g. example.com:8888/dynamic/recognize

I think this is the relevant code:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        settings = dict(
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static"),
            autoescape=None,
        )

        handlers = [
            [...]
            (r"/client/dynamic/recognize", HttpChunkedRecognizeHandler),
            [...],
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

[Source](https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server/blob/25274489f2f04f5d144a592fbf661db46f12a463/kaldigstserver/master_server.py)

I'm not familiar with Tornado, but looking at `tornado.web.Application` [docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.settings), I don't see any mention of timeouts in `settings`.

I saw several other similar questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364774/set-timeout-to-an-http-request-in-tornado), but they deal with the client side. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328555/165753) seems relevant, but I'm not sure how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado does not have a generic timeout mechanism since it is often used for long-polling and similar requests. The application (in this case, gstreamer) is responsible for managing whatever timeouts it wants to set on its own.